# How to add items from a list to a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a `List` and I want to add the `Items` specified in the `List` to a `String`.

I get the `List` from a DB server and the count of `Items` in `List` can be changed.

for example:

```
un_list = [davidsr, johnds, paulaz]
```

My string needs to be like the following:

```
my_string = '"participants": [\
  { "type": "user",\
       "username": "davidsr" },\
   { "type": "user",\
      "username": "johnds"}\
   { "type": "user",\
      "username": "paulaz"}\
]'
```

So I need to add the following for each `Item` (username) from the `List` in order:

```
{ "type": "user",\
   "username": "username"}\
```

Comment: Do you mean you need a JSON string?

Comment: Yes, I need to append the `Items` to a `JSON string` in the format I have specified in the question.

Comment: You're supposed to work with objects first and then export to JSON when you're done, not manually put together a JSON string as you go.

Comment: you need  to create a new list like `new_list = []` and something like `[new_list.append({'type' : 'user', 'username': elem}) for elem in new_list]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can populate the list of dicts with list comprehension, then use `json.dumps` to convert it to string format:

```
import json

un_list = ['davidsr', 'johnds', 'paulaz']
data = {"participants": [{ "type": "user", "username": i} for i in un_list]}
json.dumps(data)
```

Output:

```
'{"participants": [{"type": "user", "username": "davidsr"}, {"type": "user", "username": "johnds"}, {"type": "user", "username": "paulaz"}]}'
```